# Sendgrid Send Email

Tags: c#, sendgrid-api-v3

I want to send an email using my account api but i want the "From" would be the sender's email instead my email on the sendgrid.

I tried using the sendgridclient but no luck, If i replace the from address that is not set on the sendgrid, it return a result forbidden.

Let's say

My Sendgrid api email is acme@yahoo.com

if i use the acme@yahoo.com "from" address it works fine

but if i use a different account say loonie@yahoo.com it  doesn't work

Comment: That's the intended behavior. Otherwise, you could spoof anyones email and send emails in their name. 

Can you explain you're use-case why you'd want to do that?

Comment: @iobert, so i am creating an application, different client , they are just using my application...I dont want my client creating a sendgrid account, It's like they are sending an email on behalf of my account api...

Comment: If they are willing to do this, they could confirm a [Single Sender Verification](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) with their email and then you could use it.